# Project downloaded from BitBucket - no such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio

I'm doing a project in c++ using Visual Studio 2013. My friend put it into BitBucket, I downloaded it using SourceTree. Now I cant compile it:

```
1>  controller.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'controller.cpp': No such file or directory
```

Same thing about all classes. I tried to remove it, import again, add in "Additional Include Directories". Still doesn't work. Any ideas why?V

Comment: Do you see the file 'controller.cpp' on Bitbucket project files?

Comment: Yes, and I have it in directory with project file.